# What's the minimum permission level to check welcome page via rest url?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest

In sharepoint 2013, I use this rest url

```
var url = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/Web/RootFolder/WelcomePage"
```

to check what the welcome page is in the current site, but it seems to not work for everyone. It's a permission issue which asks for windows authentication login in prompt.

Does anyone know what permissions I would need to change to get it to work?

Thanks

Comment: Have you changed default Permission Profiles? The only one that comes to mind is 'Use Remote Interfaces'. For an easy overview (green is default SP) https://365csi.nl/toolkit/permissionsplanner.html?l=en

Comment: I know read permission won't work, but both edit and contribute works. Do you know which specific one would get it to read those settings?

Comment: No, see link to help you tesr